# inserting list into a vector of lists std::vector<std::list<unsigned>>

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert a list into a vector of lists using
iterator insert (const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);

```
std::vector<std::list<unsigned>> output;
std::list<unsigned> originalFile = {2, 6, 3, 56, 4, 29, 9, 43, 8, 12, 
            76, 45, 90, 124, 23, 11, 56, 26, 80, 13};
auto iter = originalFile.begin(); //it has 20 positive int inside
std::list<unsigned> sortedList; 
unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int v = 0;
    
    unsigned int numFiles = originalFile.size() / m;
    unsigned int index = originalFile.size() % m; 

    if(index != 0){
        numFiles += 1;
    }   
        while(numFiles != v)
        {       
            while(i != m)
            {
                sortedList.push_back(*iter);
                i++;
                iter++;         
            }
            sortedList.sort();

// the error point to this line with the insert function
       output.insert(output.end(),sortedList.begin(),sortedList.end()); 

            
    v++;
    i = 0;
    sortedList.clear();
  }
```

AND
I get the following two errors when I am building the file with ./build

1. `/usr/lib/llvm-11/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:1701:19:error: no viable overloaded '=' *__result = *__first;`
2. `/usr/lib/llvm-11/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:1710:12: error: no matching function for call to '__copy_constexpr'     return __copy_constexpr(__first, __last, __result);`

I also tried to use push_back instead but I get `Segmentation fault` error when I run the gtest with ./run gtest. It built successfully but the test fail.

```
for(auto iterList = sortedList.begin(); iterList != sortedList.end(); iterList++)
{           
    output[v].push_back(*iterList);
}
```

Also, I tried using the above code with `output.at(v).puch_back(*iterList)`, but built successfully and it gives me  error `C++ exception with description "vector" thrown in the test body.`

Comment: [Edit] to show a minimal compilable example

Comment: and if quoting errors, tell us which lines they are diagnosed at. Until then, I vote to close as incomplete.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting a question here. I added information.

Comment: `output` is a vector of list, so I would expect something like `output.push_back(sortedList);`

Comment: Much better, thanks, but ideally report also the lines in your source that trigger those errors, not just the ultimate lines buried in the stdlib header.

Answer (score 4):

```
output.insert(output.end(), sortedList.begin(), sortedList.end());
```

This would append a *range* of elements (between the iterators) to the end of the vector. You could do that if you had - for example - `std::vector<unsigned> output` and `std::list<unsigned> sortedList`. However, you want to insert the *list* as a whole into a *vector of lists*. The list would then be one element

```
output.insert(output.end(), sortedList); // <-- copy/move insertion
```

That looks a little awkward. Better use

```
output.push_back(sortedList);
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! I was stuck on this one for a while.